# Ganache installation steps for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ethereum, blockchain, ganache

Ganache GUI installation issues on ubuntu

Download app image from source :https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/
Right click on the file and go to Properties option
Under the "Permissions" tab, check the "Allow executing file as a program" checkbox;
Double click to run;

If its still not work you can do following :
Run an AppImage with the --appimage-extract option and it will create the directory squashfs-root
navigate to cd myapp.AppImage.squashfs-root

Run the application: Inside the extracted directory, you should find the application files. Look for an executable file, often named the same as the application. You can run it using the ./ prefix. For example in our case it will be name ganache, double click it and it should work